# Multiple instances of custom directive, confusion with ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I've created a custom directive to render a slider for a question (essentially wrapping jquery ui slider). The directive takes an ngModel and updates it when the user uses the slider, and there's a $watch attached to the parent model (the ngModel passed to the directive is only a part of a parent model). The directive has multiple instances on a page.

I've encountered an issue with the watch, as it seems as the watch always occurs on the last question on the page. So for example a page with 10 question, using the slider on question 1 - triggers the watch on the last question (question 10). I believe the issue has something to do with directives/isolated scope and/or the watch function, but I'm unable to solve it.

```
this.app.directive('questionslider', () => {
    var onChangeEvent = (event, ui) => {
        updateModel(ui.value);
    };

    var onSlideEvent = (event, ui) => {
        updateUi(event, ui);
    };

    var updateUi = (event, ui) => {
        $(ui.handle).find(".ff-handle-glyph > div").css("top", (ui.value) * - 10);
    }

    var updateModel = (newValue) => {
        // find value in values list...
        angular.forEach(isolatedScope.model.PossibleValues, function(value) {
            if (parseInt(value.Name) === newValue) {
                isolatedScope.$apply(function() {
                    isolatedScope.model.Value = value;
                });
            }
        });
    };

    var isolatedScope: any;

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            isolatedScope = scope;
            scope.$watch(ngModelCtrl, function() {
                // use provided defaultValue if model is empty
                var value = isolatedScope.model.Value === null ? isolatedScope.model.DefaultValue : isolatedScope.model.Value;

                element.slider({
                    min: 0,
                    max: isolatedScope.model.PossibleValues.length,
                    value: value.Name,
                    change: onChangeEvent,
                    slide: onSlideEvent
                });
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Code to add watch in controller

```
this.$scope.questions.forEach(function(question) {
    this.$scope.$watch(
        function() { return question; },
        function(newVal, oldVal) { this.updateQuestion(newVal, oldVal) },
        true
    );
});
```

UpdateQuestion function (right now just outputting current question)

```
function updateQuestion(newVal, oldVal) {
    // prevent event on initial load
    if (newVal === oldVal) {
        return;
    }

    console.log(newVal);
}
```

The ng-repeat markup instantiating questionsliders

```
<div data-ng-repeat="question in Questions">
    <h4>{{question.QuestionText}}</h4>
    <p>{{question.RangeMinText}}</p>
    <questionslider ng-model="question"></questionslider>        
    <p>{{question.RangeMaxText}}</p>
</div>
```

Question JSON would look like this

```
{
    "DefaultValue": {
        "Id": "5",
        "Name": "5"
    },
    "Id": "1",
    "IsAnswered": false,
    "PossibleValues": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "2"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3",
            "Name": "3"
        },
        {
            "Id": "4",
            "Name": "4"
        },
        {
            "Id": "5",
            "Name": "5"
        },
        {
            "Id": "6",
            "Name": "6"
        },
        {
            "Id": "7",
            "Name": "7"
        },
        {
            "Id": "8",
            "Name": "8"
        },
        {
            "Id": "9",
            "Name": "9"
        },
        {
            "Id": "10",
            "Name": "10"
        }
    ],
    "QuestionText": "hows it haning?",
    "RangeMaxText": "not good",
    "RangeMinText": "Very good",
    "Type": 0,
    "Value": null
}
],
"Title": "Question title",
"Type": 0
}
```

So issue is, no matter which question I update with the slider directive, it's always the last on page passed into updateQuestion.

**UPDATE**
I tried using $watchCollection, but nothing seems to fire the event.

```
this.$scope.$watchCollection(
    'questions',
    function (newVal, oldVal) {
        // prevent event on initial load
        if (newVal === oldVal) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
            if (newVal[i] != oldVal[i]) {
                this.$log.info("update : " + newVal.Id);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

I also tried with

```
function() { return questions; }
```

as first expressions. Still no luck.

Maybe using individual controllers for each question is my only option, but it seems a bit of a workaround.

**UPDATE**
So i tried using individual controllers for each question, adding a watch per question in the controller, and the strange thing is that even this is reproducing same scenario. It's still the last question on the page passed into the watch function.

markup

```
<div data-ng-repeat="question in Questions" data-ng-controller="QuestionInstanceController">
    <h4>{{question.QuestionText}}</h4>
    <p>{{question.RangeMinText}}</p>
    <questionslider ng-model="question"></questionslider>        
    <p>{{question.RangeMaxText}}</p>
</div>
```

Controller code

```
app.controller('QuestionInstanceController', function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.question); // outputs correct question here!
        $scope.$watch(
            function() { return $scope.question; },
            function(newValue, oldValue) { 
                console.log(newValue); // always outputs last question on page
            },
            true);
    }
}
```

It must have something to do with my custom directive, am i somehow overwriting previous instances when having multiple instances on the page?

Comment: Can you put a few samples from the view HTML as well?

Comment: I'd also suggest that naming a value in the directive's isolated scope "ngModel" is in poor form and confusing.

Comment: Hi Michael, i added the markup. I thought ngModel was best-practice for this kind since its something thats being updated, but it's not because it's an isolated scope, is that correct?

Comment: I'm talking about naming "scope: {ngModel: '='}" as ngModel in your directive.  Also "scope.ngModel.Value === null".  You are using ngModel as the name of a scope variable.  You should use the ng-model directive in your View, though, as you are. I'll try to sort this out for you.

Comment: The TypeScript is not clear enough for me to understand. I had no idea what you were doing in the $watch.  I can't really help further since this isn't in Javascript and I'm suspecting that something in your code that I can't recognize is to blame.  Sorry.

Comment: I should have posted plain JS in the beginning. Anyway i converted it to plain JS, hopefully functionality makes sense now? :) Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: I updated directive with the use of ngModel directive, but still no luck :\

Comment: Hi there, any other suggestions on this? I'm really anxious to know how i wil be able to solve this issue. Thanks for the time and effort.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on vacation skiing for two weeks. I'll look if I can, but I don't have a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i managed to find the solution myself. The issue was that i had a "var isolatedScope;" in the directive which was assigned on every run of the link(). I thought vars declared in the directive were isolated on each instance but infact they are overwritten on every implementation of the directive.

The solution therefore was to move the implementation of onChange directly to the init of the slider component, and thus avoiding the need of access to the scope variable later

```
this.app.directive('questionslider', () => {
    var onChangeEvent = (event, ui) => {

    };

    var onSlideEvent = (event, ui) => {
        updateUi(ui.value, ui.handle);
    };

    var updateUi = (value, element) => {

    }

    var onStartSlide = (event, ui) => {

    }

    var onEndSlide = (event, ui) => {

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/questionSlider.html',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: (scope: any, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl: ng.INgModelController) => {
            scope.$watch(ngModelCtrl, () => {
                // use provided defaultValue if model is empty
                var value = scope.model.Value === null ? scope.model.DefaultValue : scope.model.Value;
                var hasNoValue = scope.model.Value === null;

                if (hasNoValue) {
                    element.find('.ui-slider-handle').addClass('dg-notset');
                }

                element.slider({
                    min: parseInt(scope.model.PossibleValues[0].Name),
                    max: scope.model.PossibleValues.length,
                    value: parseInt(value.Name),
                    slide: onSlideEvent,
                    start: onStartSlide,
                    stop: onEndSlide,
                    animate: true,
                    change: (event, ui) => {
                        // find value in values list...
                        angular.forEach(scope.model.PossibleValues, (val) => {
                            if (parseInt(val.Name) === ui.value) {
                                scope.$apply(() => {
                                    scope.model.Value = val;
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        onChangeEvent(event, ui);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your $scope.$watch logic is throwing you off.  The simplest way might be to put a watch on the entire array of questions using $watchCollection:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(questions, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    for(index=0; index<newValue.length; index++) {
        if (newValue[index] !== oldValue[index]) {
            console.log("Question " + index + " updated to: " + newValue[index]);
        }
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you could probably create a separate controller for each item in your ng-repeat loop and have a watch there that deals with the change.  I don't love this solution, either, as it's kinda long-winded.  First, a new controller for dealing with the questions:

```
app.controller('QuestionCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('question', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newVal === oldVal) {
                return;
            }

            console.log(newVal);
    }
});
```

With your view slightly modified to include a reference to the new QuestionCtrl:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="question in Questions" ng-controller='QuestionCtrl'>
    <h4>{{question.QuestionText}}</h4>
    <p>{{question.RangeMinText}}</p>
    <questionslider ng-model="question"></questionslider>        
    <p>{{question.RangeMaxText}}</p>
</div>
```

[This article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2450-using-ngcontroller-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm) gives more information about using controllers with ng-repeat.

I hope one of these helps you out.

Comment: I updated the question with my findings with these suggestions above.